# Печать PDF файла, несколько страниц на листе

Tags: c#, pdf, print

Есть файл PDF, нужно написать кодец который, распечатывает данный файл с разбиением несколько страниц на одном листе (к примеру 4,8 на 1), я использую библиотеки Spire.PDF, Spire.Document (source: https://www.e-iceblue.com/Introduce/pdf-for-net-introduce.html#.W5d0JvYnZPY), и ZetPdf (source: https://zetpdf.com/).
Если работать через компоненты Spire.Pdf, то я использую такой метод (код взят из документации)

```
internal static void splitPdfFileByBookmarks()
    {

        using (PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument(PdfConformanceLevel.Pdf_A1A))
        {
            pdf.LoadFromFile(@"d:\PdfFiles\10_11_1808_p.pdf");
            pdf.FileInfo.Version = PdfVersion.Version1_7;
            PdfPageBase pageBase = pdf.Pages.Add(PdfPageSize.A4, new PdfMargins());
```

> здесь умещаем на одну страницу 4 стр.
>   сохраняю док., он так же сохраняется без разбиения

```
            pdf.PrintSettings.SelectMultiPageLayout(1,4);

            pdf.SaveToFile(@"d:\PdfFiles\file.pdf",FileFormat.PDF);
        }
    }
```

Если использовать компонент ZetPdf, то есть разбиение только 2стр. на 1, но не более.

```
 string filename = "Portable Document Format.pdf";
            File.Copy(Path.Combine("../../../../../PDFs/", filename),
              Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), filename), true);

            // Create the output document
            PdfDocument outputDocument = new PdfDocument();

            // Show single pages
            // (Note: one page contains two pages from the source document)
            outputDocument.PageLayout = PdfPageLayout.SinglePage;

            XFont font = new XFont("Verdana", 8, XFontStyle.Bold);
            XStringFormat format = new XStringFormat();
            format.Alignment = XStringAlignment.Center;
            format.LineAlignment = XLineAlignment.Far;
            XGraphics gfx;
            XRect box;

            // Open the external document as XPdfForm object
            XPdfForm form = XPdfForm.FromFile(filename);

            for (int idx = 0; idx < form.PageCount; idx += 2)
            {
            // Add a new page to the output document
```

> в этом участке кода добавляется страница, попробовал создать page_2
>   и добавить page
>   ошибка 'The page cannot be added to this document because the document already owned this page.'

```
            PdfPage page = outputDocument.AddPage();
            page.Orientation = PageOrientation.Landscape;
            double width = page.Width;
            double height = page.Height;

            int rotate = page.Elements.GetInteger("/Rotate");

                gfx = XGraphics.FromPdfPage(page);

                // Set page number (which is one-based)
                form.PageNumber = idx + 1;

                box = new XRect(0, 0, width/4, height/2);
                // Draw the page identified by the page number like an image
                gfx.DrawImage(form, box);

                // Write document file name and page number on each page
                box.Inflate(0, -10);
                gfx.DrawString(String.Format("- {1} -", filename, idx + 1),
                  font, XBrushes.Red, box, format);

                if (idx + 1 < form.PageCount)
                {
                // Set page number (which is one-based)
                form.PageNumber = idx + 2;

                    box = new XRect(width / 4, 0, width/4 , height/2);
                    // Draw the page identified by the page number like an image
                    gfx.DrawImage(form, box);

                    // Write document file name and page number on each page
                    box.Inflate(0, -10);
                    gfx.DrawString(String.Format("- {1} -", filename, idx + 2),
                      font, XBrushes.Red, box, format);
                }
            }

            // Save the document...
            filename = "TwoPagesOnOne_tempfile.pdf";
            outputDocument.Save(filename);
            // ...and start a viewer.
            Process.Start(filename);
```

может кто-либо сталкивался с такой задачей? сейчас копаю другие компоненты, может кто подскажет какие - либо решения.

Comment: ответ был найден)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сам же и нашёл ответ, неправильно подошёл к рассмотрению задачи, первоначально имеем документ, формируем 2 страницы на одном листе (код отсюда брал: http://www.pdfsharp.net/wiki/TwoPagesOnOne-sample.ashx), когда документ сформировался, снова повторяем туже операцию с документом 2х1 , выходит что на листе у нас 4 или 8 страниц